# How can I add animation on Path

Tags: animation, swiftui, path, shapes

I made custom button with Shape. When I click on custom Shape. I changed path CGPoint.
I wanna change this points with animation but I couldn't. How can I do this ?

[image]

**ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonStatus: ButtonStatus = .left
    @State var foo: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        BarButton(buttonStatus: buttonStatus)
            .frame(width: 125, height: 45)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: foo)
            .onTapGesture {
                //                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                buttonStatus = buttonStatus == .left ? .right : .left
                //                }
            }
    }
}
```

**BarButton**

```
struct BarButton: Shape {

    private var buttonStatus: ButtonStatus
    
    var animatableData: ButtonStatus {
        get { return buttonStatus }
        set { buttonStatus = newValue }
    }
    
    init(buttonStatus: ButtonStatus) {
        self.buttonStatus = buttonStatus
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 12 : rect.minX + 18, y: .zero))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 15 : rect.maxX - 12, y: .zero))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 13 : rect.minY + 14), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 5, y: .zero), control2: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + 7))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 5 : rect.maxX, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.midY + 15 : rect.minY + 30), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.midY : rect.minY + 15), control2: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 5 : rect.maxX, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.midY + 15 : rect.minY + 30))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 20 : rect.maxX - 10, y: rect.maxY), control1: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 8 : rect.maxX, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxY : rect.maxY - 5), control2: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.maxX - 10 : rect.maxX - 5, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 12 : rect.minX + 10, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: .zero, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.midY + 10 : rect.maxY - 10), control1: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 5 : rect.minX + 4, y: rect.maxY), control2: CGPoint(x: .zero, y: rect.maxY - 5))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? .zero : rect.minX + 7, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minY + 15 : rect.minY + 9))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 12 : rect.minX + 18, y: .zero), control1: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? .zero : rect.minX + 9, y: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minY + 7 : rect.minY + 4), control2: CGPoint(x: buttonStatus == .left ? rect.minX + 5 : rect.minX + 12, y: .zero))
            path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Animation by animatableData works interpolating values from A to B... what kind of animation did you expected between true and false? Rethink what you really want to change to be animatable.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) commented, `animatableData` works by interpolating its values, so it needs to be of a type that "can be interpolated", such as a `CGFloat` (e.g. Changing its value from 0.0 to 5.0, will interpolate all values in between).

In your case, you are defining `animatableData` as a `ButtonStatus` (I guess it is an `enum`). So it does have no clue on how to apply the interpolation when changing values.

However, you can define how interpolation should be handled for a given custom type by making it conform to [VectorArithmetic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vectorarithmetic).

Note that in your case, as the effect produced by changing the `animatableData` value varies from `CGPoint` to `CGPoint` in the path, you should probably extract some logic so these changes may be all defined by a single interpolation logic.
[Here](https://swdevnotes.com/swift/2021/how-animate-shape-change-in-swiftui/) is an article in which `VectorArithmetic` is used to animate a path defined by multiple curves (Similar to what you want to achieve).

---

**Note:** Be aware you are applying an animation on `foo` change, which has nothing to do with the button's shape change, so make sure to also replace it with the value that actually defines its shape.